# Optimal code for loading arbitrarily white-spaced delimited files

Tags: apache-pig

I was wondering if anyone could offer an improvement over the following.

I run into white-space delimited files where the number and type of
white-space delimiters can vary from line-to-line and even between
fields within a line, as suggested visually here:

whiteSpaceDelimitedFields.txt:

```
f11     f12 f13 ...
f22 f22  f23 ...
f32  f32    f33 ...
```

For this white-space general case, I use the following PIG code snippet which works
(as shown by the output below):

```
grunt> A = LOAD 'whiteSpaceDelimitedFields.txt' USING TextLoader() AS (line:chararray);
grunt> B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line, '\\s+')) AS (f0:type, f1:type, ...);
grunt> DUMP B;

(f11,f12,f13)
(f22,f22,f23)
(f32,f32,f33)
grunt>
```

I imagine that this transformation happens within the map() method (as opposed to dynamically in a Record Reader -- though I'm not sure about that); but in any case is there a PIG improvement for this oft occurring case? A loader suggestion perhaps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create a custom loader you can have a look at Piggybank's [MyRegExLoader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MyRegExLoader.html) :

```
REGISTER '/my_pig_home/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar'
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MyRegExLoader(
  '(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)') as 
  (field1:chararray, field2:chararray, filed3:chararray);

dump A;
(f11,f12,f13)
(f22,f22,f23)
(f32,f32,f33)
```

Comment: Thank you Lorand. I will try this loader. (Side note: I'd up-vote your recommendation, however I haven't used the site long enough to have the necessary 15 score to do so.)